# How do I print all even Fibonacci numbers in ARM assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm, fibonacci

In ARM assembly I was *partially* able to get the following code to work.

It is supposed to print out all of the even Fibonacci numbers from 1 to 10,946 inclusive.  I was able to print out the sum of all those even numbers.  However, I am having a problem with getting it to print out '2' as one of the Fibonacci numbers - it starts of at '8'.  I've tried changing stuff around but it just messes it up.

Here is the code that I have :

```
.equ SWI_PrStr, 0x69 
.equ SWI_PrInt,0x6b 
.equ Stdout, 1 
.equ SWI_Exit, 0x11 
.global _start
.text
_start:

MOV R2,#0 @Starting value of 0 to register 1
MOV R3,#1 @starting val of 1 to register 2
LDR R4,=10946 @register gets this value

LOOP: 

CMP R5,R4
BGE After
ADD R5,R3,R2 @adding to check if its odd
MOV R2,R3   @ answer is 0
MOV R3,R5   @result is in R5 adds to R2 is 0=1
MOV R7, R5
AND R8, R7, #1
CMP R8, #1
BGE LOOP
MOV R1, R5
SWI SWI_PrInt
LDR R1, =NL 
SWI SWI_PrStr 
ADD R6,R6,R5 @sum of the even numbers
MOV R0,#Stdout
LDR R1, =NL 
SWI SWI_PrStr

B LOOP

    After:
    MOV R1,R6
  SWI SWI_PrInt
    SWI SWI_Exit
.data
NL: .asciz"\n"
```

How do I rewrite the code so that it will print out '2', along with all the other numbers?

Comment: try moving `MOV R0,#Stdout` to top? you don't do that in prior prints, but probably works after first loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is the troublesome line:

```
MOV R0,#Stdout
```

Because of where it is, it only gets executed *after* an even number is printed - if `R0` contains the wrong value initially, the "2" is probably being printed to the wrong place. By the time you get to the next value ("8"), `R0` has been set (and presumably nothing else touches it so it stays that way) so later output goes to `Stdout` correctly.

Moving this line to the 'setup' code above `LOOP:` ought to fix it.

---

While I'm at it, there's an optimisation you could make by using test instead of compare - instead of this:

```
MOV R7, R5
AND R8, R7, #1
CMP R8, #1
BGE LOOP
```

you could simply have this:

```
TST R5, #1      @ TST is a bitwise AND
BNE LOOP        @ Not equal? What?
```

That apparently misleading condition is because we're testing whether the result is 1 or 0 - since integer comparison with `CMP` is done as subtraction, "equal" is synonymous with "zero result", and "not equal" with "nonzero result".